# why can't I inherit the function class with Int() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

The code below is a class which inherits the function inside the body. if I use Any() then the class is inheritable, but if I use Int() then the class is not inheritable. How can?

```
fun main (){
    number().me(23)
    number2().me(23)
}

class number : Int(){
    fun me(x : Int){
        println("I'm $x years old")
    }
}

class number2 : Any(){
    fun me(x : Int){
        println("I'm $x years old")
    }
}
```

can anyone explain to me? :)

Comment: I think the error message is explanation enough: 
`Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'Int'  This type is final, so it cannot be inherited from`. Did you get a different one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a derivative class from this. By default kotlin make it as a 'final' class, and a final class will not be able to has a derivate class (inheritable).

```
class AnyClassName
```

But you can make a derivative from this class, just add 'open' keyword in front of it

```
open class AnyClassName
```

Int() class in kotlin is a final class, so it is inheritable. You can open it's declaration and you'll see this

```
public class Int private constructor() : Number(), Comparable<Int> {..}
```

Any() in the other side is 'open' class, as it has keyword open in front of it. You can make derivated classes from it. Any() is also the root of all clasess in kotlin.

If you wanna add functionality to Int() class you can make an extension function, instead of making derivative from it (cause you can't of course). So in your case

```
fun Int.number() : Unit {
    println("I'm $this years old")
}
```

and in your main function

```
fun main (){
    23.number()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance):

> All classes in Kotlin have a common superclass `Any`, that is the
> default superclass for a class with no supertypes declared:
>
> ```
> class Example // Implicitly inherits from Any
> ```
>
> Any has three methods: `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()`. Thus, they
> are defined for all Kotlin classes.
>
> By default, Kotlin classes are final: they can’t be inherited. To make
> a class inheritable, mark it with the `open` keyword.
>
> ```
> open class Base //Class is open for inheritance
> ```

[`Int` is not declared with `open`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/#int), so you cannot extend it.